# How to rank and filter in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, new-operator, rank

I am new to VBA and each month I extract a data set of 5000 ratings of companies. I have managed to get the data into the below format. What I need to do is end up with a single 'rating' for each company.

For example, I have 'Market Weight', 'Underweight' and 'Overweight'. If the company has any market weight rating then I want to use that for the overall rating, but if thats not there then underweight then if not that overweight.

The issue is each company represented by a ticker, has several ratings and what I want to do is only take the one. so in the image  below, take ARNC we should end up with one rating as Market Weight for ARNC. For BBDBCN is should be underweight as there isn't any market weight present.

[Link to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzwwD.png)

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi, I want help in determining the true rating to associate with a company as a company may have been rated underweight and overweight or market weight for its different subsidiaries. So far I have worked to create a script that gets me this far as the data was a mess before. With this I tried custom sorts etc. but had no luck... I am trying hard and appreciate help so I can be better going forward. I have been stuck on this for a week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a weight column and a helper table for the weights in order to solve your problem

Find below a screenshot

[image]
You can use the below formulae

[image]

Formulae are as below

```
Cell C2: =VLOOKUP(B2,$E$2:$F$4,2,0)
Cell I2: =MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=H2,$C$2:$C$11))
Cell J2: =INDEX($E$2:$E$4,MATCH(I2,$F$2:$F$4,0))
```

Formula is Cell I2 is an an array formula, after entering or editing it you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: thank you for your help. 2 points. 1) I am getting '0' and '#NA' for BBDBCN Column I and J when I copy the formula in exactly, any idea why? 2) Would this be suitable to use for thousands of tickers and companies etc. to analyse all at once?

Comment: Formula is Cell I2 is an an array formula, after entering or editing it you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter